# Why is click requesting both __unix and __win?

Tags: dependency-management, conda-build

I'm trying to `conda build` a Python project that uses the `click` package.
I'm getting a conflicts report from `conda` ending with:

```
The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/osx-arm64::__unix==0=0
  - feature:|@/osx-arm64::__unix==0=0
  - click -> __unix
  - click -> __win
```

**Why is `click` requesting *both* `__unix` and `__win`?!**